# Image angle illusion

Tags: optics, soft-question, terminology

I am not sure whether this question on-topic here. (*please suggest to migrate if this is off-topic*)

What is the phenomenon/illusion (*or something else?*) known as where in a photo of a person, the person seems to be seeing us even when watched from any direction/angle of that photo? (*excluding backside of photo, only 180 degree*)

This can be seen when the photo is captured in linear to the person's eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to find correct tags for my post. so, added "optics".

Comment: When a person looks at you, his pupils turn towards you, appearing in the center of the white of the eye. That is why you learn to interpret this position of pupils as the person looking at you. If you look at the photo of a person where pupils are also in the centered (because the person was looking into the camera), you will get the impression that the person is looking at you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the name of an optical illusion.

Comment: @gigacyan that is what I meant in my post. I want to know what is that phenomenon known as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you're looking for is [*ubiquitous gaze*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquitous_gaze), or also *pursuing eyes*. This is an optical illusion (which means that it is exclusively a function of how our brain interprets its visual inputs) and it can be realized on completely flat canvas by appropriate handling of perspective. For more information see e.g. [this HowStuffWorks page](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/artwork/eyes-in-painting-follow.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking at a real person, as you move, their images changes: from the left, you see their left side image, from the right, you see their right-side image. This phenomenon is call [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax), and is partly responsible (in addition to binocular vision), for depth perception. In [monocular vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception#Binocular_cues), parallax is the only cue.

[In a painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception#In_art), there is generally no parallax. As you move from left to right, the image does not change in any way, to show the left and right sides of the subject.

It is possible, using thicker paint, or shaping of the canvass (ie. sticking ping-pong balls over the eyes), to overcome the lack of parallax.

Answer (score 0):

would notEssentially, what is going on is that the light, shadow and perspective depicted in a painting are fixed, meaning they don't shift. If a real person stared forward and you walked from side to side,  his or her eyes will not follow you because the light and shadow, as well as perspective you see, actually change. Features that were close to you as you stood on one side are farther away when you stand on the other side. Since the elements of perspective and light and shadow are fixed in a painting and don't change, they look pretty much the same no matter from what angle you look at it